# python Keyboard library - no output, but no error message

Tags: python, python-keyboard

I have the keyboard library running fine on one mac. On another mac, using the same commands, it runs without error, but there is no output.

Any ideas? Sorry, no code to replicate other than:

```
pip install keyboard

import keyboard


keyboard.write('hello world')

keyboard.press_and_release('commmand + tab')
```

Answer (score 0):

solved by allowing terminal access in Accessibility